# lock and unlock in multi thread java

Tags: java, multithreading, locking

I use lock and unlock in the my code And start some Customer and Producer Thread.
line lock.waite throws IllegalMonitorStateException.Why?
With the lock, the conditions for using this list are not provided in one Thread?

```
 static class Customeer extends Thread {
            private List<String> list;
            private Lock lock;
            public Customeer(List<String> list, Lock lock) {
                this.list = list;
                this.lock = lock;
            }
            @Override
            public void run() {   
                lock.lock();
                if (list.size() == 0) {
                    try {
                        list.wait();
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
                    list.remove(0);
                    lock.unlock();
            }
        }
    
        static class Producer extends Thread {
            private List<String> list;
            private Lock lock;
            public Producer(List<String> list, Lock lock) {
                this.list = list;
                this.lock = lock;
            }
            @Override
            public void run() {
                    lock.lock();
                    list.add("hello");
                    list.notify();
                    lock.unlock();
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> line `lock.wait` throws `IllegalMonitorStateException`. Why?

Actually, there is no such line.

However, there is a line that calls `list.wait()`.   And **that** is the cause of your problems.

In order to call `wait()` on an object, you must first be holding the primitive mutex lock on that object.  You can only get *that* kind of lock using `synchronized`.  (Either a `synchronized` method or a `synchronized` block.)

In your case:

- You are calling `wait` on the `List` instance.
- You are locking the `Lock` instance.
- You are holding the wrong kind of lock for `Object.wait`.  You are holding a `Lock` lock, not holding a primitive mutex lock.

So ... if you want to do the equivalent of wait and notify on a `Lock` instance, then when you need to do is to call `Lock.newCondition()` to get a `Condition` object.  Then you use it like this:

```
private final Lock lock = ...
private final Condition cond = lock.newCondition();

try {
    lock.acquire();
    while (!the_condition_we_are_waiting_for) {
        cond.await();
    }
    // do stuff
} finally {
   lock.release();
}
```

For reference, the above would look like this if you rewrote it to use a primitive mutex.

```
private final Object lock = new Object();

synchronized(lock) {
    while (!the_condition_we_are_waiting_for) {
        lock.wait();
    }
    // do stuff
}
```

(You could use *any* object as the lock, but it is a good idea to use an object that is hidden, and won't be locked by any other code.)

---

In summary, either use a primitive mutex with `synchronized`, `Object.wait` and `Object.notify*` OR use a `Lock` with `Lock.acquire`, `Lock.release`, `Condition.await` and `Condition.signal`.  Don't try to mix the two kinds of locking and condition variables.

Answer (score 1):

You have some problems with your code, namely:

1. `list.wait();` you can't acquire the list's monitor unless you are within a synchronized method (or block code).
2. `list.notify();`, you can't release the list's a monitor unless you are within a synchronized method (r block code).

You can't use `.wait()` or `.notify()` from none synchronized method or section.

Change your code like that snippet:

```
 static class Customeer extends Thread {
            private List<String> list;
            private Lock lock;
            public Customeer(List<String> list, Lock lock) {
                this.list = list;
                this.lock = lock;
            }
            @Override
            public void run() {   
                lock.lock();
                if (list.size() != 0) {
                   list.remove(0);
                }                      
                lock.unlock();
            }
        }
    
        static class Producer extends Thread {
            private List<String> list;
            private Lock lock;
            public Producer(List<String> list, Lock lock) {
                this.list = list;
                this.lock = lock;
            }
            @Override
            public void run() {
                    lock.lock();
                    list.add("hello");                    
                    lock.unlock();
            }
        }
```

These strings are calling `IllegalMonitorStateException`.

Comment: Do you mean that the lock does not work like a synchronized block?